# Как перехватить исключение Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Не получается правильно сделать **try catch**, сделал так:

```
import java.sql.*;

try { 
    String sql = "Select test From testi";
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
    List results = query.list();       
    request.setAttribute("result", results);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    request.setAttribute("name","Выберите № ");
}
```

Eclipse ругается на **SQLException**  Как правильно словить и обработать исключение? всем спасибо

Comment: Что значит ругается? Как ругается? Какими словами ругается?

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov Да конечно извиняюсь, вот так: Unreachable catch block for SQLException. This exception is newer thrown from the try statement body

Comment: Ну, все правильно, SQLException - это cheсked exception. Eclipse вам говорит, что в вашем коде его нет. А Hibernate бросает [HibernateException](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/HibernateException.html). Это unchecked exception.

Comment: @enzo Большое спасибо за помощь и разъяснения.